# Performing mouse button click

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent, desktop-application

I am currently building an app to **control mouse cursor through keyboard**. I am using the following code for mouse events:

```
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Private Sub Mouse_Click(ByVal button As Integer, ByVal state As String)

    Select Case button
        Case 1
            If state = "down" Then
                mouse_event(2, 100, 100, 0, 0)
            Else
                mouse_event(4, 100, 100, 0, 0)
            End If
        Case 2
            If state = "down" Then
                mouse_event(8, 100, 100, 0, 0)
            Else
                mouse_event(16, 100, 100, 0, 0)
            End If
        Case 3
            If state = "down" Then
                mouse_event(32, 100, 100, 0, 0)
            Else
                mouse_event(64, 100, 100, 0, 0)
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

After that in order to perform clicking:

```
Mouse_Click(1, "down")
Mouse_Click(1, "up")
```

The previous codes worked fine to perform all mouse button click through keyboard.
All I want to do is that:

Performing a long left click press for selecting and dragging features by pressing a certain keyboard button to perform `Mouse_Click(1, "up")`

I have tried several things but in vain. I know that the answer maybe very simple but I couldn't reach it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using 100 in these calls makes very little sense.  Use 0 and try again.  Your pinvoke declaration is wrong, don't try this in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @Hans: It would be really helpful to give reasons for your statements. Why is 100 a bad value, what is bad about the declaration, why not in x64 mode, ... Don't forget, be helpful, not smart-ass (NOM)

Comment: Hmm, I've posted over 10,000 answers.  Little risk of me forgetting to be helpful, thanks for your concern.  If the OP can't explain why he thinks 100 is a useful value then I can't post a helpful answer of course.

Comment: @HansPassant  It is working using 100 and after using 0 instead there is no change.